# ¿Por que no me sale el mensaje de error en el login?

Tags: php

```
  extract($_REQUEST);
  try {
   $conexion=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=restaurante", "root","");
   // Línea idonea para informarnos error de la excepcion.
   $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   //Configuramos a la conexión los caracteres hispanos
   $conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

  // Sentencia sql para divisar los datos del usuario y contraseña.
  $sql="select * from usuarios where usuario= :usu and contraseña= :contra";

  // Consulta preparada mediante la función prepare.
  $resultado=$conexion->prepare($sql);

  // El siguiente paso es rescatar lo que viene del formulario y manejar la seguridad de los caracteres.
  $usuario=htmlentities(addslashes($_REQUEST['login']));
  // En password hacemos lo mismmo.
  $contraseña=htmlentities(addslashes($_REQUEST['password']));

  //Identificamos los marcadores de la sentencia sql usando la sentencia bindValue.
  $resultado->bindValue(":usu", $usuario);
  $resultado->bindValue(":contra", $contraseña);

  //Ahora necesitamos ejecutarla. Al no imprimir datos en pantalla no necesitamos ninguna función de array.
  $resultado->execute();

  //Ahora necesitamos ver si la variable resultado devuelve un registro mediante la función rowCount.
  $numero=$resultado->rowCount();

  //Mediante un condicional le decimos que hacer si el usuario esta registrado o no.
  if ($numero!=0){
    // Si el usuario está registrado le decimos que
    session_start();

    //Luego almacenamos en la variable súper global SESSION el usuario que se ingresa en el formulario.
    $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_REQUEST["login"];
      header("location:index.php");
  }else {

    header("location:Login.php");
    echo "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta";

  }

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Fallo en la línea ". $e->getLine();
} ?>
```

Comment: Pues porque tienes que imprimirlo en el login.php, no en ese archivo donde haces validaciones e inicias sesión.

Puedes intentar mandándole como parametro ese String:
$var = "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta";
 header("location:Login.php?variable=".$var);

Y en el login.php lo usas así:
if (isset($_GET["var"])) {
echo $_GET["var"];
}

Answer (score 1):

Pues porque tienes que imprimirlo en el login.php, no en ese archivo donde haces validaciones e inicias sesión. Puedes intentar mandándole como parametro ese String:

```
$var = "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta"; 
header("location:Login.php?variable=".$var);
```

Y en el login.php lo usas así:

```
if (isset($_GET["var"])) { echo $_GET["var"]; }
```

Donde le estás diciendo que si está definica una variable llamada "var" en la url, proceda a imprimírtela.

Comment: Muchas gracias eso era

Comment: @Jesu Si la respuesta te ha solucionado el problema, podrías aceptarla como válida. Para marcar una respuesta como aceptada, haz clic en el check al costado de la respuesta para cambiarla de vacía a verde, obtendrás +2 de reputación. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Jesu? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde y te dará 2 puntos de reputación). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!